# Javascript with Special Chartecter

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page in which I need to pass a String variable to javascript function. This works until String does not have a special charecter.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function test(v){
                alert(v);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Test Button" onClick="test('BlahBlah')"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

As soon as I change onClick like below, it stops working.

```
onClick="test('Blah'Blah')"
```

Any solution for this problem. Please take a note parameter which is being passed to JavaScript function is dynamic.Source of Parameter is backend and I cannot change that peice of code. Second thing even if put escape it still does not work. My problem is I have to retian the special charecter for some processing at backend

Comment: You need to escape any single ticks, other than that you won't have a problem. Also, what's the source of the parameter, your back-end?

Comment: Source of Parameter is backend and I cannot change that peice of code. Second thing even if put escape it still does not  work. Please give a try at you end. My problem is I have to retian the special charecter for some processing at backend.

Comment: Sounds like you're simply not escaping it properly.

Comment: If you can't change the backend, then you can't stop it from generating invalid JS, and you are more or less screwed. (I can think of a lunatic hack to try to work around it, but couldn't possibly recommend it)

Comment: Yes I am screwed. I tried replace as well but it did not work.

Comment: *"Source of Parameter is backend and I cannot change that peice of code."* Say what? If the backend is failing to output valid HTML, or is outputting invalid JavaScript code in attributes, then that backend is badly broken. It needs fixing. If you're not allowed to fix it, you'll need to make noise at whoever *is*.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a client-side workaround that works if about a dozen caveats happen to be true. Best we can do without fixing the backend. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two layers to this:

1. The content of `onClick` attributes, like all attributes, is *HTML text*. That means that any character that's special in HTML (like `<`) must be replaced with an HTML entity (e.g., `&lt;`). Additionally, if you use double quotes around the attribute value, any double quotes *within* the value must be replaced with entities (`&quot;`); if you used single quotes around the attribute, you'd need to replace `'` with `&apos;`.
2. Your attribute contains a JavaScript string literal. That means that any characters that are special inside JavaScript string literals must be escaped according to the JavaScript rules. Since you've used single quotes to delimit the JavaScript string, for instance, you have to escape any single quotes *in* the string with a backslash.

I'm assuming that HTML is generated server-side. If so, the work above must be done server-side, when building the HTML of the page. You haven't said what server-side tech you're using, so it's hard to point you at solutions that your server-side tech/environment might provide.

In the simple case of your

```
onClick="test('Blah'Blah')"
```

...you just need to add the backslash within the JavaScript string

```
onClick="test('Blah\'Blah')"
```

...but that's just that one specific case.

The *dramatically* simpler option is to *not* put JavaScript code in attribute values. Instead, use modern techniques (`addEventListener`, `attachEvent`) to hook up JavaScript code.

But if you must use an `onClick` attribute, avoid having text in it (or deal with the complexities above); have it call a function defined in a `script` element that then has the text, as you then have only the one layer (#2 above) to deal with.

---

> Source of Parameter is backend and I cannot change that peice of code.

That backend is broken and needs fixing.

**If**:

- the backend is only producing invalid JavaScript code (not invalid HTML)
- *and* the code consists of a single function call
- *and* the code is always a single function call
- *and* the function call always has a single string literal argument
- *and* that argument is always delimited with single quotes
- *and* the single quotes *within* the string are never correctly escaped

...we might be able to salvage it client-side. But my guess is that the backend will also produce invalid HTML, for instance when the text has a `"` in it. (We can't do anything about that, because the attribute value will be chopped off at that point.)

But let's keep a good thought: Given the ridiculous list of caveats above, this might do it:

```
var elm = document.getElementById("the-div");
var code = elm.getAttribute("onclick");
var m = code.match(/^([^(]+)\('(.*)'\)$/);
if (m) {
    code = m[1] + "('" + m[2].replace(/'/g, "\\'") + "')";
}
elm.setAttribute("onclick", code);
```

Live Example:

```js
function foo(str) {
  alert(str);
}

var elm = document.getElementById("the-div");
var code = elm.getAttribute("onclick");
var m = code.match(/^([^(]+)\('(.*)'\)$/);
if (m) {
    code = m[1] + "('" + m[2].replace(/'/g, "\\'") + "')";
}
elm.setAttribute("onclick", code);
```

```html
<div id="the-div" onclick="foo('blah'blah')">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is an very common problem you wanted to add single quotes inside single quotes to do this you have to escape that Sigle quotes to do that you have to put an forward slash.

```js
onClick="test('Blah\'Blah')"
```